# Web Api Upload to Azure Storage - Request Entity Too Large

Tags: azure, iis, web-config, blob, storage

I'm trying to upload a file from a Web App to Azure Storage via Web Api (in different domain). Even though I'm increasing the maxRequest length in Web Api, I'm getting an exception 413: Request Entity Too Large once I try to upload a file over 4mb. Is there any limit in Azure Storage that I can set to fix this problem?

```
    public string UploadFromByteArray(Byte[] fileStream, string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            ConfigureCors(account);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //throw;
        }
        // set the content type to image
        //blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/pjpeg";

        //blob.Metadata.Add("ModelName", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        //blob.SetMetadata();
        var permissions = BlobContainer.GetPermissions();
        permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
        BlobContainer.SetPermissions(permissions);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = BlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
        blob.UploadFromByteArray(fileStream, 0, fileStream.Length);

        return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    }

    private void ConfigureCors(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount)
    {




        try
        {
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            ServiceProperties blobServiceProperties = new ServiceProperties()
            {
                HourMetrics = null,
                MinuteMetrics = null,
                Logging = null,
            };

            blobServiceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule()
            {
                AllowedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
                AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Head | CorsHttpMethods.Post,
                AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() { "*" },
                ExposedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
                MaxAgeInSeconds = 3600 // 30 minutes 

            });

            blobClient.SetServiceProperties(blobServiceProperties);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
//
//

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
//
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>

    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="2100" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- 100 MB in bytes -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" maxQueryString="104857600" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.0" newVersion="3.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you post your full web config?

Comment: just added the web.config of Web Api.  @jdruid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I could manage to fix my problem by setting the SingleBlobUploadTresholdInBytes to max. value. Not sure if this is the correct solution though. Here is the ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.singleblobuploadthresholdinbytes(v=azure.10).aspx

```
        BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();
        options.SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes = 67108860;
        blob.UploadFromByteArray(fileStream, 0, fileStream.Length, options:options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage has limits on the size of blobs that you can upload. All the details can be found in the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179451?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but I excerpt a relevant portion:

> The maximum size for a block blob created via Put Blob is 64 MB. If your blob is larger than 64 MB, you must upload it as a set of blocks. For more information, see the Put Block and Put Block List operations. It's not necessary to also call Put Blob if you upload the blob as a set of blocks.
>
> If you attempt to upload a block blob that is larger than 64 MB, or a page blob larger than 1 TB, the service returns status code 413 (Request Entity Too Large). The Blob service also returns additional information about the error in the response, including the maximum blob size permitted in bytes.

Comment: 64mb is quite enough in my case. Apparently this is not my current problem. I'll check IIS settings